# After adding a lot of info into Realm one of my items do not work

Tags: objective-c, realm

I've been facing a very strange problem in Realm which doesn't occur every time , but it's been really annoying.

I'm saving a lot of information offline which come from a Webservice using realm. I don't get any exception while saving all these information. 
Later I'm able to get all these objects by accessing them through MyObject.allObjects().

These objects contains a property which is an UUID, which I use to download the file related to this object and save it locally, after I finish downloading the file, I update my Realm Object with the path of the file, but some times when I do it:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "UUID = %@", fileId)
print("This is the select \(pred.predicateFormat)")
let results = IssueFile.objects(with: pred) as! RLMResults<IssueFile>
```

The variable results is empty, but if I check Realm Database via `Realm Browser`, I can find the item I'm looking for.

So my question is: why some times Realm can't find the object I'm selecting? As I'm saving a lot of information, is there something I should change in the Realm Configuration?

I've already set the UUID as primary key of the table:
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"UUID";
}

Thanks,

Comment: As you're using a UUID String for your file to be identified, have you tried to make it your `IssueFile`'s Primary Key? It would be simplier using the method `+objectForPrimaryKey:` with your UUID as parameter.

Comment: Interesting, I've added it as primary key and I didn't know this one, I'm gonig to try it!

Comment: I haven't found this function neither in the object nor in the realm docs, do you implemented it by your own?

Comment: From your code I can assume you're using realm-cocoa (not realm-swift), this is the documentation for this method: https://realm.io/docs/objc/2.10.2/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)objectForPrimaryKey:

Comment: You're right, if you want to put your answer as a reply, I can upvote it

Comment: Sounds good! Doing it now with a little more deep explanation.

Comment: I'm using it with Swift and I can't find this method, have you tried it with in a Swift code? in Swift the method is called `init(forPrimaryKey:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163971/discussion-between-orlando-and-renan-camaforte).